# Pyspark cast integer on a double number returning 0s

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

In my PYspark dataframe, I have column whose type is double. Below is the data it is holding:

```
|            HV ratio|
+--------------------+
|4.819714653321546E-6|
|6.290848613094555E-6|
|4.669412994783916E-6
```

I am trying to round-off the numbers to 2 decimal places. Below is the query that I am running:

```
hv_ratio.select(format_number(hv_ratio["HV ratio"].cast('integer'),2).alias('HV ratio')).show()
```

But it is returning zeroes instead(as shown below):

```
|HV ratio|
+--------+
|    0.00|
|    0.00|
|    0.00|
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real number for `4.819714653321546E-6` is **`0.000004819714653321546`**.

When you cast to **`int`** value becomes **`0`** then `format_number` to round `2` we will get `0.00` instead round to **`>5`** decimal places then you will see actual values.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("new_hvratio", format_number(col("HVratio"),21)).show(10,False)
#+--------------------+-----------------------+
#|HVratio             |new_hvratio            |
#+--------------------+-----------------------+
#|4.819714653321546E-6|0.000004819714653321546|
#+--------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this answer. Its very immature on my part. I should have noticed that negative exponent. Anyways, thanks again.